# what is correct way to use golang AddDate to calculate date

Tags: go

Today is 2018-11-1, I use AddDate to calculate 7 days: 
startTime := time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, -7).Unix(), but 2018-10-25 still exist. What is the correct way to calculate date use AddDate method?

Answer (score 3):

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> ```
> import "time"
> ```
>
> [func (Time) AddDate](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.AddDate)
>
> ```
> func (t Time) AddDate(years int, months int, days int) Time
> ```
>
> AddDate returns the time corresponding to adding the given number of
>   years, months, and days to t. For example, AddDate(-1, 2, 3) applied
>   to January 1, 2011 returns March 4, 2010.
>
> AddDate normalizes its result in the same way that Date does, so, for
>   example, adding one month to October 31 yields December 1, the
>   normalized form for November 31.

---

`startTime := time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, -7)` calculates the time minus 7 (-7) days or 7 days ago.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Round(0))
    startTime := time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, -7)
    fmt.Println(startTime)
}
```

Output (right now in the US it is 2018-10-31 21:30:40 EDT):

```
2018-10-31 21:30:40.977401051 -0400 EDT
2018-10-24 21:30:40.977510166 -0400 EDT
```

In your time zone, it is currently 2018-11-01, so minus 7 (-7) days or 7 days ago is 2018-10-25.

---

Note: There are two ways to count days. For age, today you are one day older than yesterday. For pay, working yesterday and today is two days pay.

Comment: thanks, it that means, if I want 7 days, include today, I should minus 6 days, right?

Comment: @sophiageng: Yes. Minus 0 days is today, one day by your count, minus 1 day is yesterday, two days by your count, and minus 6 days is seven days by your count. .